# Clang-format 10.0 vs. 5.0 const member fuction is formated differently

Tags: c++, constants, member-functions, clang-format

We are updating our clang-format from 5.0 to 10.0 (yes, I know that this is a big jump :-))
The file `.clang-format` is kept constant.

With the 5.0 version we get a format like this

```
virtual Composite *copy_composite_tree(Composite *parent  // parent of copied tree
                                      ) const;
```

With the 10.0 version this changes to

```
virtual Composite *copy_composite_tree(Composite *parent  // parent of copied tree
) const;
```

Is there an option to keep the 5.0 formatting style?

Comment: Try dumping configuration for both version and check where the default value of a property is changed. Add that property with original value to your `.clang-format` file. Or you can try experimenting with properties on some online configurator like https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/

Comment: I would highly recommend going over changelogs to update your .clang-format file. I'm sure some options have been deprecated, and lots of new ones added. This is on top of the previous suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider this to be a bug, which was introduced with clang-format 9.0.1, since all buildin styles, such as LLVM, Google, ... show the very same behaviour.

I reported this bug to the llvm project.

https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46509

Answer (score 2):

I'd assume this is simply governed by bracket alignment just like everything else, quoting clang documentation:

AlignAfterOpenBracket (BracketAlignmentStyle)
If `true`, horizontally aligns arguments after an open bracket.
This applies to round brackets (parentheses), angle brackets and square brackets.

Possible values:

BAS_Align (in configuration: Align) Align parameters on the open bracket, e.g.:

```
someLongFunction(argument1,
                 argument2);
```

BAS_DontAlign (in configuration: DontAlign) Don’t align, instead use ContinuationIndentWidth, e.g.:

```
someLongFunction(argument1,
    argument2);
```

BAS_AlwaysBreak (in configuration: AlwaysBreak) Always break after an open bracket, if the parameters don’t fit on a single line, e.g.:

```
someLongFunction(
    argument1, argument2);
```